# Find best match for a string

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries.

```
mydict1 ={                                                                                           
    'Better' : {'vara1':'vala1', 'varb1':'valb1'},                                                                                   
    'BetterThanBest' : {'vara2':'vala2', 'varb2':'valb2'} }

mydict2 = {                                                                                                                                                            
    '/check12/BetterThanBest':'/dir3/BetterThanBest' }                                                                                                                                                                

for i in mydict2 :                                                                                                                                                     
    for pattern in mydict1.keys() :                                                                                                                                    
        if pattern in i : 
           print pattern, i                                                                                                  
           # Do something for i, 
           # but don't want multiple matches to i, just the best
```

This returns :

```
 Better /check12/BetterThanBest
 BetterThanBest /check12/BetterThanBest
```

I would like to find an exact match for the keys of mydict1, i.e. in the above case "BetterThanBest". Is it possible ?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: How do you define 'exact match'?

Comment: As you can see in this example, mydict2 contains the word 'BetterThanBest' and that's the match I would want, not part of the word which matches to 'Better'.

Comment: So, for '/check12/BetterThanBest' would you like to match that against both 'check12' and 'BetterThanBest'? or just the last entry ('BetterThanBest')?

Comment: '/check12/', I don't want to match or even if it matches, I would like to separate it out...

Comment: So you are trying to match the last component of the path (the part after the last slash) to a set of candidate strings, then if it matches one of them, operate against that whole candidate path?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do poor man's anchoring with `startswith` and `endswith`, but really, you probably want to use regexes or full equality checking with tokenization of your candidate string to match exactly how you want.  Or use an ordered key store, organize your search terms based upon superset>subset>subsubset, then break out of the search routine on first find.  Making a few assumptions:

```
pattern_dict = {'Better' : {'vara1':'vala1', 'varb1':'valb1'},                                                                                   
                'BetterThanBest' : {'vara2':'vala2', 'varb2':'valb2'}}
candidate_dict = {'/check12/BetterThanBest':'/dir3/BetterThanBest' } 
for candidate, candidate_value in candidate_dict.iteritems():
    try:
        match_pattern = pattern_dict[candidate.rsplit('/', 1)[-1]]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    else:
        # do stuff for each matched candidate and it's matched pattern dict
```

Comment: If you are going to -1 an answer that is in no way incorrect, at least say why.

Comment: I didn't do this... I don't know who did ! Someone also -1 the question ... what the heck ? I also asked in the question : 'is it possible' ? of course everything is possible :-) ...

Comment: There, I just undo the -1 someone else did to your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
In [43]: mydict1 ={                                                                                           
   ....:     'Better' : {'vara1':'vala1', 'varb1':'valb1'},                                                                                   
   ....:     'BetterThanBest' : {'vara2':'vala2', 'varb2':'valb2'} }

In [44]: mydict2 = {                                                                                                                                                            
   ....:     '/check12/BetterThanBest':'/dir3/BetterThanBest' }

In [51]: keys1=sorted(list(mydict1),key=len,reverse=True) #sort the keys by length, descending order

In [52]: keys2=sorted(list(mydict2),key=len,reverse=True) #sort the keys by length, descending order

In [54]: [x for x in keys1 for y in keys2 if x in y][0]
Out[54]: 'BetterThanBest'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your requirements are not very clear to me, but assuming what you want to do is match the keys of `mydict1` against the the last word in the keys of `mydict2`(with `/` being the word separator), here's how I might approach it.

```
d2_keys = dict((k.rsplit('/', 1)[-1], k) for k in mydict2)
for k in my_dict1:
  if k in d2:
    print k, d2[k]
```

What this does:

1. first, we create a new dict `d1` which maps the extracted word from each key of `mydict2` to the original value. This allows us to quickly compare keys against the extracted word, as well as map it to the original value.

   ```
   >>> d2 = dict((k.rsplit('/', 1)[-1], k) for k in mydict2)
   >>> d2
   {'BetterThanBest': '/check12/BetterThanBest'}
   ```
2. Next we iterate through the keys of `mydict1` and compare the keys against `d2`.

Caveat: This will now work as expected if the keys in `mydict2` results in duplicate words.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I don't know why all this negative points to this question, but I tried the following and it does what I want :

```
mydict1 ={                                                                                                                                                             
    'Better' : {'var1':'vala1', 'var2':'valb1'},                                                                                                                       
    'BetterThanBest' : {'var1':'vala2', 'var2':'valb2'}                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                  
mydict2 = {                                                                                                                                                            
   '/check12/BetterThanBest':'/dir3/BetterThanBest'                                                                                                                   
   }                                                                                                                                                                  

for i in mydict2 :                                                                                                                                                     
    pat ='a'                                                                                                                                                           
    for pattern in mydict1.keys() :                                                                                                                                    
        if pattern in i and pattern.__len__() > pat.__len__():                                                                                                         
            pat = pattern                                                                                                                                              

    print pat
    print mydict1[pat]["var1"]
```